# MacBook Pro screen freaks out, goes psychedelic — I'm at a loss — suggestions?

Tags: macbook-pro, display, gpu

Been using and taking care of Macs since 1985, and I've never seen this before. Can't find anything online. Anyone? Graphics card going south?

Reboot fixed the problem, but it returned 2x the next day.

Have zapped the PRAM, waiting to see if that helps.

[image: Like, wow, man. This computer is STONED.]

Comment: Just curios - do i see it right that the mouse cursor is displayed correct?

Comment: Clearly it's graphics card issue. if this a 15" MBP 2011/2012/2013, better take a look at the below link.

http://www.apple.com/support/macbookpro-videoissues/

Comment: any magnetic fields near ?

Comment: @Buscar - magnetic fields?

Comment: Pointer can be seen.

Comment: No magnetic fields — it's on the same desk as usual, no environmental changes. The one oddity is that the user has developed really bad peripheral neuropathy (numbness in hands and feet) in the wake of chemotherapy, and she thinks her body's personal electrical field may be out of whack as a result. Haven't ruled that OUT, but seems incredibly unlikely.

Comment: Thanks for the link, Pratika Rana. It's a 13" MBP 2011. Do you think a SMC reset might help, or is your guess that the card is shot and it's only going to get worse?

Comment: BTW, I'd have her take it to a genius bar, but there isn't an Apple Store for at least 300 miles.

Comment: Open the ColorSync utility app (in the Utility folder), than check and Change the Color profile. This is since the cursor is showing not distorted at all, but all other colors are. Also to est, go to System Pref - Accessibility- Display, and change to Gray Scale.

Comment: I have a 2010 MBP (model also known to have graphics card issues) and had similar corruption, but it generally didn't affect the window I was using. I used it for several months like that, but eventually it died completely. I suggest you get it repaired soon so that you get to choose when.

Comment: Thank you, everyone. This is all great advice. Will probably go for new computer rather than repair, since graphics card = probably replacing motherboard = probably $700+.

Comment: Buscar웃, I'm not sure if the cursor was distorted, I just know she was able to tell where it was. But we'll give your suggestion a try and see what we get!

Comment: You can operate it fine? If you can. You can just recalibrate in System Preferences > Display

Comment: It can't be magnetic fields and magnetism has no effect on an LED display.  You are confusing the effect caused when you put a magnet next to a CRT.

Comment: Good point, Allan.

Comment: Recalibrating might help. Thanks for thinking of that, TheBro21. Don't know why it slipped my mind.

Answer (score 4):

Chances are, it's hardware.

Download and burn a copy of [Ultimate Boot CD](https://www.ultimatebootcd.com)  Insert the disk and boot your Mac by holding down the "C" key.  It's a Linux OS and will boot up in text mode (not graphics intensive)

There are a number of video related tests you can run.  Since it is outside of OS X,  you are removing the OS from the equation.

Chances are, you are going to run across something hardware wise.

If you don't get errors reported back, it may be a connector or the display itself.  If you have an external monitor, hook that up and see if the problem manifests there.  If it dosen't, then you know it is something between the logic board and display.

If you do see errors, then you know for a fact it's your chip.

Don't dispair.  I have used a service that will replace graphic chips on Apple logic boards and they have been quite reliable.  I can give you the name privately, if you like.  The cost was (give or take) about $100 including shipping.

I have personally used the above techniques and vendor with zero failures thus far.

I hope this helps.

Comment: Thank, @Allan. I may take you up on your offer to connect with that service if the problem persists. And I will look into Ultimate Boot CD.

Comment: Just let me know...if I can help, I am happy to.

Comment: Is this service who's name shall be kept private, a secret service? ;)

Comment: @Todd  The company is Top Notch Macs.  The phone number is 727-488-9248.  Sorry, I don't remember the  guys name that I dealt with.  I am still using a MBP that they serviced for video issues and it is still going strong; 18 months now!

Answer (score 2):

Try booting it into Recovery and see if the problem persists there too. If it doesn't, you'll want to reinstall OS X from there. Be sure to back up all of your data before reinstalling as it will wipe the disk.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. Will try that too, if the problem persists.

Answer (score 2):

I [reset the NVRAM](https://support.apple.com/en-gb/HT204063) on my Mac (aka "zapped the PRAM") and so far it seems to have resolved the problem.

This is a simple procedure of restarting the Mac, and holding down the Command, Option, P and R keys once you hear the startup sound. You hold them until the Mac reboots again, then release them. This clears hardware settings that are stored in non-volatile RAM (NVRAM), resetting them to the system defaults.