# What is wrong with my mac?

Tags: startup, recovery

Suddenly today my good old MacBook pro from 2012 won't start. I get the gray screen of death. I have tried safe boot, recovery boot and Internet recovery boot and it all results in a static gray screen. I have tried to boot into single user mode, and typed the recommended commands with fcsk -fy but it didn't help. I have also tried reseting pram, that didn't help either. When booting in verbose mode this is where it stops, any clue? [image: first half of page] [image: second part of page]

Comment: OK it makes it till loading networks on en1 (wifi) then It says GPU hardware ..... disabled ? then it enables the en2 ? why would it do that?

Comment: I did that already

Comment: You are not, I'm just telling that I already tried that 

Comment: OK then to test if it is your GPU boot from a external USB!  Since your internal boot is corrupt.

Comment: How can i do that?

Comment: Sorry, I assumed you have a bootable USB with OS X on it? do you ? if not then ignore my suggestion.

Comment: I don't, can you even make such a disk?

Comment: Actuals it is easy, but for you not so easy. So find a friend who will do it for you. Buy a USB stick with 10 Gb space. Then get someone to install to make it bootable with OS X (Yosemite) on it). It is always good to have it specially in the situation like yours.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have answered a similar question here on [stackexchange](https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/181873/119271) and you can do some diagnostics with [Ultimate Boot CD](https://www.ultimatebootcd.com).

First thing...can you boot into "single user mode?"

1) Press the power button to start the computer.

2) Immediately press and hold the Command-S

If you are presented with a black screen and the system didn't crash then we are off to a good start.  If you want, you can get into your home directory by going to

```
/Users/<your username>/
```

and you will then see your Desktop, Documents, Music, Pictures, etc. file folders.  If you can get here, there is a good chance of salvaging/backing up all your data.

To exit single user mode, type

```
reboot
```

Next, boot the Ultimate Boot CD.  It's Linux based but it will boot on a Mac.  It also boots up in text mode (like single user) so if there is an issue with your graphics card, it won't crash.  You will find some video diagnostics once it boots; run those.

If you get errors during the video testing phase, then you know it's your graphic chip.  This is a known problem with Macs so your best bet would be to have Apple replace your logic board.

Answer (score 1):

Turns out to be this known problem https://www.apple.com/support/macbookpro-videoissues/