# iMac 21.5" Mid 2011 - Stuck on white screen at boot

Tags: imac, startup, ssd, memory

The problem is that the iMac displays the Apple logo then flashes black before getting stuck on white screen.

What I've tried so far:

- Safe Mode (<kbd>⇧</kbd>) - not working, can´t get into Safe Mode, loading bar appears below apple logo but flashes back to white screen.
- Startup Manager (<kbd>⌥</kbd>) - I tried to boot from alternative hard drive, I tried recovery HD and a USB stick with High Sierra fresh install - not working, it loads partially and flashes back to white screen.
- NVRAM/PRAM Reset (<kbd>⌘</kbd><kbd>⌥</kbd><kbd>P</kbd><kbd>R</kbd>) – I waited for two chimes but no change.
- Recovery Mode (<kbd>⌘</kbd><kbd>R</kbd>) – It loads for about 6/9 min with a world icon spinning but it doesn't work either flashes back to white screen.
- Apple Hardware Test (<kbd>D</kbd>) - No faults detected.
- I have 12GB RAM, I tried removing extra RAM and stay with standard 4GB. no change.
- Replaced Hard Drive, I moved from SATA to brand new SSD, flashes back to white screen

Can anyone help me, could it be a hardware fault such as the GPU?

Comment: This similar question was asked just yesterday.  https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/381580/macbook-pro-2011-white-screen-cant-install-macosx  It’s a hardware issue, but the OP found a work around.

Comment: @amt976 based on your descriptions I've edited your question to more accurately identify your steps based on this Apple page: https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201255

Comment: @unknowndomain - good job on the edits, but one oversight...  it’s NVRAM.  PRAM went away with PPC Macs and NVRAM came on the scene with the introduction of Intel based Macs.