# MacBook Pro Mid 2015 Display flickering to static/weird colour during usage

Tags: macbook-pro, display, color

About a day ago my 2015 MacBook Pro running macOS 10.15 Beta (19A536g) started experiencing an issue where the display would flicker to different colors randomly during usage. Moving the mouse around causes the display to revert back to its normal colors temporarily but it tends to alternate between the two very often.

I have already tried an SMC and PRAM reset as I had no ideas on what to due.
As well there is currently no system updates available.

Any ideas on what could be causing this and/or how to fix it? Any help or ideas are greatly appreciated. I'd really like to avoid bringing my laptop into the Apple store if possible.

Here is what it looks like when the display shifts colors. :[image]

Comment: Start your Mac up in a safe mode, and see if this happens or not. Also, try to login with a different user account to check. If you have done SMC, NVRAM reset and the option I shared, then mostly it could be a hardware issue. However, try those two options to see it.

Comment: Take a screenshot, display it on another computer. If the screenshot is fine (EG looks like it should with no color shifting) then the problem is likely a hardware issue

Comment: To add to Steve's answer, would recommend trying an external monitor. I suspect it is a hardware issue

Answer (score 1):

This is a hardware issue; most likely a failed GPU.

I wrote an [answer addressing this same issue](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/181873/macbook-pro-screen-freaks-out-goes-psychedelic-im-at-a-loss-suggestions/182092#182092) but diagnosing by booting a Linux is not so easy anymore.

You can attempt to run [Apple Diagnostics](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT202731) by booting and holding <kbd>D</kbd>.  It may or may not return an error code.

However, virtually every time I’ve seen something like this, it required a logic board replacement.