# MacBook suddenly start to flicker

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, mac

I have a MacBook Pro, Late 2011 with 8GB RAM and a 512GB SSD

I installed Monterey using the OpenCore patcher method.

Suddenly at random times, the screen starts to flicker. Please see the attached screenshot.

I'm doubting faulty RAM but I want to make sure. Please help me.[image]

Answer (score 2):

It could be that the graphics card is physically failing, or that as it was never designed to be Metal2 capable, it's incapable of rendering.

The test would be to go back to High Sierra, which is the maximum OS that Mac is qualified for.

Comment: I agree with Tetsujin that this could be an incompatibility issue, but if it continues to fail after reverting to a compatible version of macOS, it’s hardware.  See this [similar post](https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/375038/119271) about a MBP running a beta version of macOS with screen flickering.  Always make sure you’re back to a **known good** baseline to help you determine the cause of the problem.

Comment: And always ensure to have backups!

Comment: We can ruleout unsupported OS bcz I've Dual boot Ubuntu and it is showing same issue.