# Trying to get a MacBook Pro from 2011 running

Tags: macos, macbook-pro

I'm trying to get a MacBook Pro from 2011 running. From the start there was an account named MacBook that I had the password to. But when logging in it all ended up with a blue screen. After some digging it seemed like there was some problems with the GPU. I followed some tutorials to fix that and instead of getting a blue screen it shut down. So, I did not follow that road anymore.

What I've tried to reinstall it:

- Network reinstall (it fails, "Can't connect... to servers")
- Reinstalling OS Lion (it fails, "Can't download components...")
- Installing Ubuntu (it fails, the computer just shuts down after a while)
- Downloading a High Sierra DMG-image. Flashing an USB using Windows 11. However I can't get it to boot from the USB.

Do you have any suggestions how to try to get this MacBook running again? It still is a fairly nice computer, after all these years. Thanks for any help.

Comment: Linux Mint was running on this one from an USB and the installation went fine. However, when I log in into Linux Mint it freezes. I'm stuck at a black screen with the cursor arrow, which I cannot move. :/

Comment: The 2011 models were infamous for problems with the GPU, and while there were software workarounds, it's a hardware problem. If it really won't boot from several different OSes, then the hardware is broken.

Comment: @benwiggy Thanks for the reply. Finally, I managed to install a Linux Distro on it: Manjaro Plasma. Seems to be running just fine, so far. I don't like it though and will go for Manjaro Gnome instead.

Comment: It may depend on what drivers are used, of course.

Comment: Instructions for creating a Lion through Sierra bootable USB installer from Windows is given [here](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/309399/how-can-i-download-an-older-version-of-os-x-macos/460961#460961).

Comment: [Similar question about a 2011 MBP](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/182092/119271). You likely have a faulty GPU as @benwiggy has already indicated.

Comment: @DavidAnderson Thanks for the link. However, I decided to stick with Manjaro for now.

Answer (score 0):

I gave up on the macOS-installations and after trying installing 1) Ubuntu 2) Linux Mint 3) Fedora (all failed) Manjaro Linux did the trick. The only real issue I had was that the WiFi did not work. Don't install Manjaro Linux if you don't have an ethernet port on your MacBook since you will need it to fix the WiFi. Here's a solution on how to fix the WiFi:
https://forum.manjaro.org/t/macbook-pro-2011-no-wifi-adapter-found/146683/1